# How to limit number of concurrent jobs that are starting by Pig script?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to implement simple data processing flow for POC in Pig using [Hortonworks sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/).

The idea is following: there is some set of already processed data. New data set should be added to old data without duplicates.

For testing purpose I use very small data sets (less than 10 KB).
For virtual machine I've allocated 4GB of RAM and 2 of 4 processor cores.

Here is my Pig script:

```
-- CONFIGURABLE PROPERTIES
%DEFAULT atbInput '/user/hue/ATB_Details/in/1'
%DEFAULT atbOutputBase '/user/hue/ATB_Details/out/1'
%DEFAULT atbPrevOutputBase '/user/hue/ATB_Details/in/empty'

%DEFAULT validData 'valid'
%DEFAULT invalidData 'invalid'
%DEFAULT billDateDimensionName 'tmlBillingDate'
%DEFAULT admissionDateDimensionName 'tmlAdmissionDate'
%DEFAULT dischargeDateDimensionName 'tmlDischargeDate'
%DEFAULT arPostDateDimensionName 'tmlARPostDate'
%DEFAULT patientTypeDimensionName 'dicPatientType'
%DEFAULT patientTypeCodeDimensionName 'dicPatientTypeCode'

REGISTER bdw-all-deps-1.0.jar;

DEFINE toDateDimension com.epam.bigdata.etl.udf.ToDateDimension();
DEFINE toCodeDimension com.epam.bigdata.etl.udf.ToCodeDimension();
DEFINE isValid com.epam.bigdata.etl.udf.atbdetails.IsValidFunc();
DEFINE isGarbage com.epam.bigdata.etl.udf.atbdetails.IsGarbageFunc();
DEFINE toAccounntBalanceCategory com.epam.bigdata.etl.udf.atbdetails.ToBalanceCategoryFunc();
DEFINE isEndOfMonth com.epam.bigdata.etl.udf.IsLastDayOfMonthFunc();
DEFINE toBalanceCategoryId com.epam.bigdata.etl.udf.atbdetails.ToBalanceCategoryIdFunc();

rawData = LOAD '$atbInput';

--CLEANSING
SPLIT rawData INTO garbage IF isGarbage($0),
    cleanLines OTHERWISE;

splitRecords = FOREACH cleanLines GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0, '\\|'));

cleanData = FOREACH splitRecords GENERATE
    $0 AS Id:LONG,
    $1 AS FacilityName:CHARARRAY,
    $2 AS SubFacilityName:CHARARRAY,
    $3 AS PeriodDate:CHARARRAY,
    $4 AS AccountNumber:CHARARRAY,
    $5 AS RAC:CHARARRAY,
    $6 AS ServiceTypeCode:CHARARRAY,
    $7 AS ServiceType:CHARARRAY,
    $8 AS AdmissionDate:CHARARRAY,
    $9 AS DischargeDate:CHARARRAY,
    $10 AS BillDate:CHARARRAY,
    $11 AS PatientTypeCode:CHARARRAY,
    $12 AS PatientType:CHARARRAY,
    $13 AS InOutType:CHARARRAY,
    $14 AS FinancialClassCode:CHARARRAY,
    $15 AS FinancialClass:CHARARRAY,
    $16 AS SystemIPGroupCode:CHARARRAY,
    $17 AS SystemIPGroup:CHARARRAY,
    $18 AS CurrentInsuranceCode:CHARARRAY,
    $19 AS CurrentInsurance:CHARARRAY,
    $20 AS InsuranceCode1:CHARARRAY,
    $21 AS InsuranceBalance1:DOUBLE,
    $22 AS InsuranceCode2:CHARARRAY,
    $23 AS InsuranceBalance2:DOUBLE,
    $24 AS InsuranceCode3:CHARARRAY,
    $25 AS InsuranceBalance3:DOUBLE,
    $26 AS InsuranceCode4:CHARARRAY,
    $27 AS InsuranceBalance4:DOUBLE,
    $28 AS InsuranceCode5:CHARARRAY,
    $29 AS InsuranceBalance5:DOUBLE,
    $30 AS AgingBucket:CHARARRAY,
    $31 AS AccountBalance:DOUBLE,
    $32 AS TotalCharges:DOUBLE,
    $33 AS TotalPayments:DOUBLE,
    $34 AS EstimatedRevenue:DOUBLE,
    $35 AS CreateDateTime:CHARARRAY,
    $36 AS UniqueFileId:LONG,
    $37 AS PatientBalance:LONG,
    $38 AS VendorCode:CHARARRAY;


--VALIDATION
SPLIT cleanData INTO validData IF isValid(*),
    invalidData OTHERWISE;

--Dimension update--

--MACROS
DEFINE mergeDateDimension(validDataSet, dimensionFieldName, previousDimensionFile) RETURNS merged {
    dates = FOREACH $validDataSet GENERATE $dimensionFieldName;
    oldDimensions = LOAD '$previousDimensionFile' USING PigStorage('|') AS (
        id:LONG,
        monthName:CHARARRAY,
        monthId:INT,
        year:INT,
        fiscalYear:INT,
        originalDate:CHARARRAY);
    oldOriginalDates = FOREACH oldDimensions GENERATE originalDate;
    allDates = UNION dates, oldOriginalDates;
    uniqueDates = DISTINCT allDates;
    $merged = FOREACH uniqueDates GENERATE toDateDimension($0);
};


DEFINE mergeCodeDimension(validDataSet, dimensionFieldName, previousDimensionFile, outputIdField) RETURNS merged {
    newCodes = FOREACH $validDataSet GENERATE $dimensionFieldName as newCode;
    oldDim = LOAD '$previousDimensionFile' USING PigStorage('|') AS (
        id:LONG,
        code:CHARARRAY);
    allCodes = COGROUP oldDim BY code, newCodes BY newCode;

    grouped = FOREACH allCodes GENERATE  
        (IsEmpty(oldDim) ? 0L : SUM(oldDim.id)) as id,
        group AS code;
    ranked = RANK grouped BY id DESC, code DESC DENSE;
    $merged = FOREACH ranked GENERATE
        ((id == 0L) ? $0 : id) as $outputIdField,
        code AS $dimensionFieldName;
};

--DATE DIMENSIONS
billDateDim = mergeDateDimension(validData, BillDate, '$atbPrevOutputBase/dimensions/$billDateDimensionName');
STORE billDateDim INTO '$atbOutputBase/dimensions/$billDateDimensionName';

admissionDateDim = mergeDateDimension(validData, AdmissionDate, '$atbPrevOutputBase/dimensions/$admissionDateDimensionName');
STORE admissionDateDim INTO '$atbOutputBase/dimensions/$admissionDateDimensionName';

dischDateDim = mergeDateDimension(validData, DischargeDate, '$atbPrevOutputBase/dimensions/$dischargeDateDimensionName');
STORE dischDateDim INTO '$atbOutputBase/dimensions/$dischargeDateDimensionName';

arPostDateDim =  mergeDateDimension(validData, PeriodDate, '$atbPrevOutputBase/dimensions/$arPostDateDimensionName');
STORE arPostDateDim INTO '$atbOutputBase/dimensions/$arPostDateDimensionName';

--CODE DIMENSION
patientTypeDim = mergeCodeDimension(validData, PatientType, '$atbPrevOutputBase/dimensions/$patientTypeDimensionName', PatientTypeId);
STORE patientTypeDim INTO '$atbOutputBase/dimensions/$patientTypeDimensionName' USING PigStorage('|');

patientTypeCodeDim =  mergeCodeDimension(validData, PatientTypeCode, '$atbPrevOutputBase/dimensions/$patientTypeCodeDimensionName', PatientTypeCodeId);
STORE patientTypeCodeDim INTO '$atbOutputBase/dimensions/$patientTypeCodeDimensionName' USING PigStorage('|');
```

The problem is that when I run this script it never completes (gets stuck).
In Job Browser I can see one completed job and multiple jobs with 0% progress.

[image: Job browser]

If I comment out processing of last three files - everything works fine (i.e. three parallel jobs succeed).

I've tried few approaches to fix this issue:

1. **-no_multiquery** Pig parameter - allows to execute script completely using only one job at time. Main disadvantage is huge number of generated jobs (26) and very long execution time (near 15 mins for described script and almost 40 mins for more complicated version).
2. Work only with parts that I develop and test by commenting out other parts - this is not an option for long term perspective.
3. Change **mapred.capacity-scheduler.maximum-system-jobs** property in **mapred-site.xml** so there should be less than three jobs at once [as described here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/capacity_scheduler.html#Job+initialization).
4. Change **mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.default.maximum-capacity** in **capacity-scheduler.xml** for configuring default queue. But this approach didn't worked for me as well as previous.
5. Allocate more memory for sandbox virtual machine and mappers and reducers - no effect.

So my question is how can I limit the number of concurrent jobs that are starting by Pig script?
Or maybe there is other configuration fix that allow concurrent execution of multiple jobs?

---

[UPDATE]

If I run the same script with the same input data from shell console - everything works fine.
So I assume that there is some issue with HUE.

---

[UPDATE]

If I start more complex script from console it also gets stuck, but in this case number of parallel jobs is 8.

Comment: First, your mistake is to try to profile using a single-node pseudo-distributed cluster. This is suited for testing that your scripts compile and produce correct output, not profiling. If you need to profile you will need to set up a real multiple-node cluster. Second, why limit number of concurrent MR jobs? Usually people are talking about number of Map or Reduce tasks... And when a huge number of tasks from one MR job is preventing the other MR job (its tasks have to wait pending) from running. Why are you trying to violate the parallel paradigm of Hadoop?

Comment: **1.** I don't try to profile. I just want have development environment that will be able to run my scripts in suitable time frame. **2.** Because if there are to many jobs they get stuck. So I want to put them into queue and process only 3 jobs at time.

Comment: Then it seems you got stuck in performance limitations and are trying to do some hacks to solve them. Maybe you can try Cloudera Quickstart VM which is similar to Hortonworks VM. Also (if you don't want to set up a hardware-based cluster) you can rent a Hadoop instance (with many nodes) in Amazon Elastic MapReduce.

Comment: As for your update about HUE - are there any differences in configurations between the user HUE runs its jobs from and the user used when you run your jobs from the console?

Comment: No, in ssh I use the same user as with web UI (i.e. hue). The only difference I've noticed is missing TempletonControllerJob in job browser. Looks that HUE uses different mechanism of script execution than pure Pig does.

Answer (score 3):

Last time we saw this it was because the cluster had [only one map task](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!searchin/hue-user/single%2420task/hue-user/vieqMBKTJIc/tSeMZWR5SxwJ).

Comment: But in my case three jobs can run in parallel. So tasks capacity is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXEC as described here:

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#Implicit-Dependencies